# Http 200 in logs, but page doesn't redirect in appengine

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have a JavaScript client on my App Engine app that listens to a channel and makes a GET request like this when there a message is posted on the client:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_ah/channel/jsapi"></script>
<script>
    channel = new goog.appengine.Channel('{{ token }}');
    socket = channel.open();
    socket.onmessage = function() {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', '/secondpage');
        xhr.send();
      };
</script>
```

After the server posts a message on the channel I can see a successful HTTP 200 response in the logs, but the page doesn't actually redirect to the new page. Here's the app log:

[image]

Any ideas why this is happening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either insert the received HTML code into the page DOM (insert/replace/append,such as [insertAfter](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/), or the straightforward *innerHTML=*), or, if you are getting a full page, 
a) send "Location: [url]" redirect 302 header on the server side, or
b) call JavaScript **window.location.reload();** to refresh the entire page on the client side ([location.reload](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp)).
 
Thank you for your attention,
Tom

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty much the whole point of a XMLHttpRequest -- the page stays as is -- anything you want to change you need to do in your code.